# Assign value not reference in Typescript method return

Tags: json, typescript, reference, clone

I am working in Ionic3.

I have a function which calls another function from `provider.ts` and it returns an interface Object.

**page.ts**

```
getList(){
  this.localdata = this.provider.getGlobalData();
}
```

**provider.ts**

```
getGlobalData(){
  return this.gvData;
}
```

Now, any changes made to `localdata` are also changing `gvData` in `provider.ts`.
I don't want to copy the reference, just the value. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following snippet will return a cloned version of your object.

**provider.ts**

```
getGlobalData(){
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.gvData));
}
```

---

You could also do it this way:

**page.ts**

```
getList(){
  this.localdata = JSON.parse(this.provider.getGlobalData());
}
```

**provider.ts**

```
getGlobalData(){
  return JSON.stringify(this.gvData);
}
```

Comment: Hit and run is amazingly annoying. This is an extremely popular way to clone objects. If there's a problem with the answer then I want to learn so I won't be making mistakes. Just downvoting it without saying why is not helpful to anyone.

Comment: Thanks, This solution worked nicely. I also want to know the reason for down vote. Saying something not right doesn't count without explanation.

Comment: You're quite welcome. I'm glad it worked and thanks for the comment!

Comment: Just facing one issue with this. In my object, the date is type Date. After I am getting the value its becoming string in the process. So it's becoming `chDate: Mon Nov 27 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)` to `hDate: "2017-11-27T05:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: Can you change it to a string before you stringify it? Or otherwise modify it somehow before it gets passed such that the stringification won't mar it?

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to use spread operator:

```
getGlobalData() {
  return { ... this.gvData};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something like a `Object.assing({},this.provider.getGlobalData())` to get a new copy of the object.

Comment: Maybe it's because the proto is the same, try to switch Object.assing with Object.create, it should provide you a different instance based on the same proto.

Comment: I don't suggest you using the JSON way because it's too expensive in terms of performance.